# My iPhone does not offer to add a .pkpass file to my Apple Wallet

Tags: node.js, passbook, wallet

I created a pass using the following node module:

https://github.com/assaf/node-passbook

Everything seems to work well.

However, when I send it to myself on email and click on it on my iPhone in the mail client, I'm not offered to add it to the wallet.

Furthermore, when I do the same on Android, this time using the WalletPasses app, it seems to be added to the wallet, but the pass is without any data. It is just plain white.

Can anybody suggest why this should happen?

The .pkpass file contains two json files and some images as seen next.

pass.json:

```
{
    "passTypeIdentifier": "dk.dsg.netto.prototype.wallet",
    "teamIdentifier": "MXL",
    "backgroundColor": "rgb(255,255,255)",
    "serialNumber": "123456",
    "description": "20% off",
    "organizationName": "Netto",
    "coupon": {},
    "formatVersion": 1
}
```

and manifest.json:

```
var x = {
    "pass.json": "9a4a67da648f5681c2036a9838c708c0e56e06ce",
    "background.png": "1769da2bbd0bde6387eb3760d2858dcc6172f3be",
    "background@2x.png": "d59976f11a91262b9c8ec443c903039fac4f89bb",
    "footer.png": "48496ca187adb375d1c91ee1a10d6e3e23991cc4",
    "footer@2x.png": "647df1d50e272771c535a37ebff26070751867f2",
    "icon.png": "0bad882eb1ec07982911651d63fe104c2101feed",
    "logo.png": "379e24c1a86fd3ef93999c67f80724fbdabc6f4c",
    "icon@2x.png": "13c375e697907a4cd72c024ab03e5a939c47e46f",
    "logo@2x.png": "109683c9ca14dbd538fb69e853cc731947a77d23",
    "strip.png": "f28bdd4775d906f952f7a84f543d9558bad5c683",
    "strip@2x.png": "39ab832f10acfb908aa75d1588ce5c6ced6f081e",
    "thumbnail.png": "12da8ac12c8b82ecacd5febc3e19aefdb6f8b2df",
    "thumbnail@2x.png": "79ba17b1255fd0a32a5ab7b3c0e93733f9dcd7db"
}
```

Comment: Can you open the pkpass on a OSX device? If you rename the .pkpass to .zip you can decompressed it and see the files, maybe you could compare this to a working pass to try find the issue. 
I have seen this issue when there was a problem with my signing certificates.

Disclosure: I work for http://flomio.com. The company behind http://passninja.com/.

Comment: No, I cannot open it on an OSX device. I compared to working passes but could not figure out what was wrong.

Comment: I've just deployed http://pkpassvalidator.azurewebsites.net/, which is a basic app for validating PKPass files. It's very simple at present, only checking the validity of Pass Type Identifier and Team Identifier, but it might be a good place to start.

Comment: manifest.json is not a valid json file if it really starts with `var x = `. I doubt you're still working on this 4 years later, but if you are, try removing those characters.